# Why WebSphere expands jar in /WEB-INF/classes

Tags: java, websphere

I have a strange problem in WebSphere 8.5.5.
I have a simple .war archive that has a jar under /WEB-INF/classes (yes, *classes*, this is not a typo). For example,

/WEB-INF/classes/my_file.jar

On WebSphere 8.5.5 I hit an exception trying to just load the application.
This is the exception (slightly shortened for the sake of clarity):

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.SaveFailureException: WEB-INF/classes/my_file.jar
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.ZipStreamSaveStrategyImpl.save(ZipStreamSaveStrategyImpl.java:327)
//
org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.SaveStrategyImpl.save(SaveStrategyImpl.java:217)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.save(ArchiveImpl.java:2388)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ModuleFileImpl.save(ModuleFileImpl.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.saveAsNoReopen(ArchiveImpl.java:2608)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.ArchiveImpl.saveAs(ArchiveImpl.java:2428)
at com.ibm.ws.management.application.client.AppInstallHelper.createEarWrapper(AppInstallHelper.java:1045)
... 41 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:47)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:501)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile$1.fill(ZipFile.java:269)
//
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.util.ArchiveUtil.copy(ArchiveUtil.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.strategy.ZipStreamSaveStrategyImpl.save(ZipStreamSaveStrategyImpl.java:320)
... 56 more
```

What I understand from the exception is that the jar file is not a valid zip file. What I am missing is why WebSphere is trying to copy and unpack it? Can I prevent WebSphere from doing this?

**update:** I see that this needs clarification. I am very well aware of Java EE war structure. The said jar is under /classes/ on purpose. At runtime, it is being located (using ServletContext.getResource()) and copied to a temp folder, and from there it is being launched in another Java process.
My question is not about Java war structure, it is about why WebSphere tries to unzip it and whether or not I can control this WebSphere behavior somehow.

**update 2:** This turned out to be a non-problem. The jar file was corrupted and was replaced. I am leaving this question here because I am still curious to know why WebSphere tries to unzip it and whether or not I can control it. The existing answers did not answer to the point being asked.

Comment: First of all you should put your jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` not to the `classes` folder. Second, I just deployed war with the jar in the classes and WAS doesn't try to expand it. So please specify what version are you using (Liberty or full) , how are you deploying your app, as it is more likely error related to Eclipse that to WAS, and why you dont put jar in WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: Please see update to the question, thanks. I don't know why profile I am using, whatever is the default.

Answer (score -1):

Please see below Java EE WAR file structure. It doesn't sound like a WebSphere problem,  it would not work across Java EE compliant application servers.

[image: Standard Java EE WAR file structure]

**Update** (Based on the updated information in question ): I see you have a very specific requirement.  Since you are using ServletContext to get the reference of the JAR file, I would recommend to design it in a new separate folder inside WEB-INF ( your JAR would be secured and ServletContext would be able to locate it.).  This way you will maintain Java EE specification standard and will be able to do what you are trying to do.